# VSIX: execute code on VS startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I'd like to call some code from VSIX extension when visual studio loads a solution, how do I do that? Package::Initialize is called only when user presses a button of my addin first time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding the following attribute to your VSPackage class:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]
```

That will trigger your package to load when a solution is opened/created.

Answer (score 4):

Author asked about VS2010, so it should be:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]
```

VSConstants sit in:

\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration
    \Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.dll