# DTEEvents.OnStartupComplete event not working for VSPackage (VSSDK2010)

Tags: envdte, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

In the Package constructor I added the event handler for OnStartupComplete event. But when I run the code, the the event handler is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Packages are deferred loaded by default.  Are you telling Visual Studio to load your package on startup?  see the answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815461/vsix-execute-code-on-vs-startup

Comment: Will, I used the PackageAutoload attribute, but this attribute works only if VS is launched by a project or solution file. If I open only the VS to open the StartPage, the package is not loaded!!

Comment: I don't believe that is true.  There are other attributes you can put on your package which tells VS that your package should be loaded only when a solution is present.  You sure you're not using one of those?

Comment: The only attributes I have on my package are, PackageRegistration, DefaultRegistryRoot, ProvideLoadKey, ProvideMenuResource, ProvideAutoLoad, ProvideToolboxItems and Guid.

Comment: Use `[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]`, `[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]`, `[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.EmptySolution)]` as attributes and the package will be loaded no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

There's a bug in VS that recycles the `DTEEvents` object (with your event handlers) unless you keep an explicit reference to it. You need something like this:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]
class MyPackage : Package
{
    DTEEvents _EventsObj;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
        _EventsObj = dte.Events.DTEEvents;
        _EventsObj.OnStartupComplete += OnStartupComplete;
    }

    void OnStartupComplete()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code from package constructor to the Initialize() method of the package. It should help, but if it doesn't, test some other UICONTEXT_??? values for your AutoLoad attribute, maybe [UICONTEXT_NoSolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.uicontext_nosolution%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/eb1e8fd1-32ad-498c-98e9-25ee3da71004

I believe that it is because you could be boxing and unboxing your DTE object before doing the event subscription. This is a huge nuisance, and quite surprising that the DTE object cant be passed around easily through service location for the purpose of event subscriptions; but this seems to be the culprit.

I had tried to keep a reference to the DTE object but it made no difference as I was doing that anyway. Some events will work, and some won't; but this is consistent.